# Can I add a third field to a .NET ListItem rendered object?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, selectlistitem

I am not so into **.NET** and **SharePoint** and I have the following doubt working on a **Web Part** into a SharePoint 2013 project.

Into my web part I have a dropdown like this:

```
DropDownList dropDownnEtichetta = new DropDownList();
```

Then I add some items to this DropDownList in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < etichettaCorrenteList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    dropDownnEtichetta.Items.Add(new ListItem(valoreDaMostrare, valoreId));
}
```

It works fine, as you can see the **ListItem** is populated passing the text shown in the dropdown and the value.

I want to know if is it possible to add a third information to this list item. In case what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2
```

shows that ListItem has not a constractor that takes three string parameters. It ha only

```
ListItem()  
ListItem(String)    
ListItem(String, String)    
ListItem(String, String, Boolean)
```

these constructors.

For ypur purpose you can extend ListItem Class.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself in this way:

```
ListItem currentItem = new ListItem(valoreDaMostrare, valoreId);
currentItem.Attributes.Add("valoreDaStampare", valoreDaStampare);

dropDownnEtichetta.Items.Add(currentItem);
```